# Extending the ConsolidatedNewsFeedWebPart Newsfeed Web Part in order to render custom Activity Events in SharePoint 2010 MySites

Tags: 2010, web-part, my-site, social, newsfeed

The title says it all and I imagine this question will evolve as more people provide input. I will try to update with the current answer and/or working code for all to use.

The question is about extending a web part, the ConsolidatedNewsFeedWebPart in particular. I have [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) installed and I have read this post, [Extending the Newsfeed](http://weshackett.com/2011/06/extending-the-activity-feed-with-enterprise-content/), from Wes Hackett many times. But since I am more or less newer to SharePoint dev, I was hoping for more help and tips on this.

So far:
I created a new web part in VS 2010 which extends the ConsolidatedNewsFeedWebPart. I added the correct assembly, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portals.Proxy.dll, and all looks good. But now how to override the rendering.

Tips on overriding the rendering and/or Reflector are welcome.